# Como hacer un split en cada "\u"?

Tags: c#

Necesito dividir la cadena donde contenga un `\u`.

Intenté haciendo lo siguente, pero no funciona.

```
string[] split = data.Split(new string[] { @"\\u" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

string[] split = data.Split(new string[] { @"\u" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Ejempo:

```
string x = "uno \u dos \u tres \r\0\0\0\0";
```

Necesito sacar a "uno", "dos" y "tres" de `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Necesito dividir la cadena donde contenga un \u

Esto te será de utilidad:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        string x = @"uno \u dos \u tres \r\0\0\0\0"; //Nótese el uso de un @ antes de la cadena.
        string[] split = x.Split(new string[] { @"\u" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach(var item in split)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Genera:

```
uno 
 dos 
 tres \r\0\0\0\0
```